# Rescaling plotting data for colordata from 1 to 0

Tags: graphics, color

Hi I would like to use ColorData function for coloring a 2D-scatter data plot using the third column of the data set. I am using `ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[#[[3]],{-100,0}, {0, 1}]]` as a color function:

```
With[{minmax = {0, 50}, fsize = 24, bw = 15, bh = 350}, Show[Legended[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8],{ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[#[[3]], 1.0*minmax, {0,1}]], Point[Most@#]}&/@data},Frame->True,BarLegend[{ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[#, 1.0*minmax, {0,1}]] &, minmax}, LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> fsize},LegendMarkerSize -> {bw, bh},"Ticks" -> Function[{min, max}, ({#, StringForm["``", #]}) & /@Range[min, max, 20]] @@ minmax]], Frame -> True,PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1]]
```

data=

```
{{4.38304, 2.60982, 20.516}, {0.431117, 1.88956, 1.13064}, {0.0582229,4.63633, 2.32156}, {2.71878, 2.39666, 8.59011}, {1.22675, 3.79948, 
  3.40465}, {4.92496, 1.08523, 24.7979}, {2.29509, 4.42365, 
  7.47924}, {2.91927, 1.31987, 9.18208}, {4.5978, 2.11918, 
  22.1994}, {4.93645, 2.93971, 25.8384}, {0.414024, 3.95107, 
  2.14695}, {3.48079, 3.75933, 13.9956}, {2.00775, 3.16371, 
  5.6129}, {4.12197, 0.527692, 17.2545}, {2.35631, 1.55, 
  6.32719}, {3.90901, 1.08184, 15.8213}, {1.05802, 4.39689, 
  3.31784}, {2.04075, 3.39338, 5.86136}, {4.28019, 0.0390898, 
  18.3396}, {3.25901, 1.61945, 11.4309}, {3.2894, 3.83488, 
  12.7376}, {3.03001, 0.127631, 9.24476}, {3.08098, 3.08007, 
  11.0324}, {4.23422, 1.95233, 18.9048}, {4.6904, 1.88286, 
  22.9413}, {4.50432, 0.604507, 20.5912}, {1.13497, 4.93169, 
  3.754}, {4.07333, 0.748265, 16.9662}, {4.52897, 1.20146, 
  21.1123}, {1.00612, 0.237351, 1.13094}, {3.48673, 0.607516, 
  12.4611}, {3.10077, 4.10944, 11.6695}, {4.91592, 1.16156, 
  24.747}, {0.432122, 4.99942, 2.68644}, {1.75302, 3.54677, 
  4.84645}, {2.28367, 2.81965, 6.62495}, {4.85932, 2.06096, 
  24.6435}, {2.8591, 2.52723, 9.43808}, {1.94136, 2.34559, 
  4.94167}, {4.84704, 4.39698, 25.6923}, {4.42866, 2.18089, 
  20.7035}, {4.59272, 0.613076, 21.3996}, {2.36778, 2.89249, 
  7.05262}, {0.306202, 0.826278, 0.506899}, {0.648587, 1.76852, 
  1.30493}, {2.22038, 4.13003, 6.99511}, {4.15851, 4.70554, 
  19.646}, {3.48244, 2.39341, 13.3241}, {0.2258, 4.04841, 
  2.07519}, {0.752728, 0.555487, 0.844342}, {4.7367, 2.50861, 
  23.6906}, {3.594, 4.64961, 15.2416}, {3.53265, 4.68163, 
  14.8204}, {0.5242, 4.24241, 2.39599}, {2.59567, 1.30383, 
  7.38944}, {4.35183, 1.5834, 19.7301}, {1.31236, 1.80784, 
  2.62621}, {0.775745, 4.22357, 2.71356}, {4.84709, 3.46594, 
  25.2273}, {2.73566, 1.55417, 8.26093}, {2.07108, 1.6464, 
  5.11257}, {1.21068, 4.56523, 3.74836}, {1.50041, 4.54478, 
  4.52361}, {4.68218, 3.71624, 23.7809}, {4.08927, 0.530658, 
  16.9874}, {0.671765, 1.16914, 1.03584}, {4.14395, 3.15679, 
  18.7507}, {2.87041, 2.8533, 9.6659}, {3.01513, 4.2718, 
  11.2269}, {0.829459, 1.0981, 1.23705}, {3.12789, 0.0611986, 
  9.81432}, {1.54913, 3.70555, 4.25259}, {0.0347729, 2.86008, 
  1.43125}, {4.52271, 0.620307, 20.7651}, {2.55848, 4.29032, 
  8.69099}, {3.39315, 3.94377, 13.4853}, {4.20777, 0.820608, 
  18.1156}, {2.96835, 3.50823, 10.5652}, {4.69089, 0.760392, 
  22.3846}, {1.04318, 1.8558, 2.01613}, {4.14719, 2.07294, 
  18.2356}, {1.64323, 1.69366, 3.54703}, {1.386, 0.643079, 
  2.24255}, {1.40564, 4.57804, 4.26484}, {2.12357, 4.07546, 
  6.54728}, {0.744434, 4.33322, 2.72079}, {4.98491, 0.420582, 
  25.0596}, {4.37361, 0.365902, 19.3114}, {4.6517, 2.76181, 
  23.0192}, {2.92235, 0.00515463, 8.5427}, {2.20708, 4.87971, 
  7.31105}, {3.50849, 0.146913, 12.383}, {2.54706, 4.91193, 
  8.94349}, {4.60709, 2.56266, 22.5066}, {3.99463, 2.55897, 
  17.2365}, {2.6397, 3.61945, 8.77775}, {3.15392, 1.80214, 
  10.8483}, {1.67531, 3.46288, 4.53809}, {4.67694, 0.32854, 
  22.038}, {4.97298, 4.71437, 27.0877}}
```

However this gives me a too much bright looking plot; instead if I use the rescaling of the data between {1,0} instead of {0,1}, then I get a reversed color order but good looking figure; Now is it phsyically meaningful or allowed to Rescale the data from 1 to 0 instead of 0 to 1, so I am currently using `ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[#[[3]],{-100,0}, {0, 1}]]`, but is it okay to use `ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[#[[3]],{-100,0}, {1, 0}]]`?

Comment: Please fix your `Ticks`  and include definitions for `ticksLeft` and `ticksDown`.

Comment: Please include `data` and make your code self-contained. Best practice would be to make your code minimal and remove all non-essential options, to focus on the actual problem (which isn't about ticks or frame labels, for example).

Comment: My dataset is fairly large, any suggestions on how do I include or post the dataset here

Comment: @Syed can you please tell me what kind of fix are you saying regarding the ticks

Comment: This is what I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzica.png).

Comment: yes, I think I have used a separate frame ticks function for ticks on the frame box, you can remove the ticksleft and ticksright if you want then, only the frame ticks will be absent then.

Comment: As @Roman suggested earlier, please present a **minimal working example** in order to get focused replies.

Comment: yes I have edited question and removed most of the frameticks, basestyle etc. parts, hopefully now it is more clearer

Comment: If your question is simply whether it’s okay to rescale to {1,0}, the answer is yes.